# TypeLoadException when storing an object that implements INotifyPropertyChanged or any other event

Tags: wpf, serialization, ndatabase

when storing an object that implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface or that contains any event in general i get the following exception :

```
NDatabase.Exceptions.OdbRuntimeException: 
NDatabase has thrown an Exception
Error:275:Class Introspectpr error for class MS.Internal.Text.TextInterface.Generics.NativeIUnknownWrapper<MS::Internal::Text::TextInterface::Native::IDWriteFont>, PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 ---> NDatabase.Exceptions.OdbRuntimeException: 
NDatabase has thrown an Exception
Error:275:Class Introspectpr error for class MS.Internal.Text.TextInterface.Generics.NativeIUnknownWrapper<MS::Internal::Text::TextInterface::Native::IDWriteFont>, PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 ---> NDatabase.Exceptions.OdbRuntimeException: 
NDatabase has thrown an Exception
Error:275:Class Introspectpr error for class MS.Internal.Text.TextInterface.Generics.NativeIUnknownWrapper<MS::Internal::Text::TextInterface::Native::IDWriteFont>, PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type from string value 'MS.Internal.Text.TextInterface.Generics.NativeIUnknownWrapper<MS::Internal::Text::TextInterface::Native::IDWriteFont>, PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at NDatabase.TypeResolution.GenericTypeResolver.Resolve(String typeName) in c:\TeamCity\Agents\A\BuildAgent\work\5f9a44f79ee7a25c\src\TypeResolution\GenericTypeResolver.cs:line 44
```

this happens when storing the object for the first time or when updating an existing object

i use this code to store the object :

```
long newid = 0;
using (var db = NDatabase.OdbFactory.OpenLast())
{
    newid = db.Store(st).ObjectId;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add the `[field: NonPersistent]` attribute to the event.
so this

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

should be changed to

```
[field: NDatabase.Api.NonPersistent]
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```